# Align div horizontally and vertically center to a page (responsive)

Tags: css

I have a div for login form .I want to align the div horizontally and vertically centered in all devices.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: margin: 0 auto;
justify-content:center;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

Comment: Now want happens is that in the mobile landscape view ,form and the footer overlaps.If a give a min-height form overlaps with header

Comment: Question already asked, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187838/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-on-page/45110782#45110782

Answer (score 13):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is better way than using `position: absolute`. Thank you.

Comment: sweet, simple, easy and perfectly working!!!!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
html body {
    height:100vh;
}

html body .login-box {
    width: 460px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -230px;
    margin-top: -250px;
}
```

Please note the height and margin top is half of the height, Also the width is half of the margin left. in case you want to change the width and height of your div.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/b7b954ox/1/

Your box must have width and height so you can use:

```
position: fixed; /* or absolute */
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```