# I'm trying to center text in the middle of my page HTML

Tags: html, css

I have three different div tags (not inside each other) with code so it has one puts words to left, center, or right but the center is very off centered. Here is HTML code:

```css
.desc {
  float: right;
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc1 {
  float: left;
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc1">
  <h2>What we are here to do!</h2>
  <p>Example</p>
</div>
<div class="desc2">
  <h2>What we have completed</h2>
  <p>Recent work (can include pictures)</p>
</div>
<div class="desc">
  <h2>Company Description</h2>
  <p>EXAMPLE!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Question already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187838/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-on-page/45110782#45110782

Comment: You need to change the order, if you want this to work. The element to be floated to the right must come first or second. If you make it the last one, then it does not affect the placement of the elements before it any more in the way you want. You should perhaps not do this using floating any more these days anyway; look into flexbox.

Comment: Can you show the code of the parent tag that contains this div s. It may be because of parent tag's width is not enough for these 3 divs?

Comment: @BilluG That's for vertical centering. Joe is asking about horizontal alignment.

Comment: @BilluG thats a different question. It may be on same subject but the implementation is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use flexbox to fix that,

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="desc1">
    <h2>What we are here to do!</h2>
    <p>Example</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc2">
    <h2>What we have completed</h2>
    <p>Recent work (can include pictures)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>Company Description</h2>
    <p>EXAMPLE!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Works fine. I was going to post a similar solution.

Comment: Can you add demo of your solution?

Comment: @VictorAllegret It will work not so good because we can here different width of elements https://jsfiddle.net/uqr20k64/1/ `space-between` just adds equal spaces between elements. This property doesn't care about equality of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.desc {
text-align: center;
color: skyblue;
width:33%
}

.desc1 {
text-align: center;
color: skyblue;
width:33%
}

.desc2 {
text-align: center;
color: skyblue;
width:33%
}
.desc4{
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class="desc4">
<div class="desc1">
   <h2>What we are here to do!</h2>
   <p>Example</p>
</div>
<div class="desc2">
   <h2>What we have completed</h2>
   <p>Recent work (can include pictures)</p>
</div>
<div class="desc">
  <h2>Company Description</h2>
  <p>EXAMPLE!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.desc2 {
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        color: skyblue;

        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -200px;
    }
```

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `<center> </center>` tag. It works quite well for this.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to put the center tags in code format so they didn't show up. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `desc2` contents are technically centered, relative to the remaining space. Your `desc` (right column) is getting pushed below the rest of your content because it will start floating from the point where the content of `desc2` ends.

The easiest solution is to move `desc` up above `desc2` so that the left/right floated items come first, and will start at the same y-position.

After that, if you want to ensure your main content is truly centered, you may need to specify a width for your left/right columns.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is actually wrap those 3 divs inside another div, and apply a *display : flex* to this main div, like so :

```css
.main {
display : flex;
justify-content : space-between;
}

.desc {
  float: right;
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc1 {
  float: left;
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="desc1">
    <h2>What we are here to do!</h2>
    <p>Example</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc2">
    <h2>What we have completed</h2>
    <p>Recent work (can include pictures)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>Company Description</h2>
    <p>EXAMPLE!</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Since the *float* property have some strange behaviour in some conditions, *display : flex* is much more appropriate when you want to display several parts side by side. I really recommend you to learn a little bit more about those flex properties, they are really time-saving. I hope it might help you.

Comment: it will work not so good because we can here different width of elements jsfiddle.net/uqr20k64/1 `space-between` just adds equal spaces between elements. This property doesn't care about equality of elements.

Comment: I didn't really understand, but do you mean that if there is, for example, an element with width : 900px; one with width : 200px and another with width : 20px;, there will be the same amount of space between each of them ?
I don't see where is the problem then...

Comment: OK, let's see if this is OK for OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a wrapper around the existing divs and define a flexbox for it.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10%;
}

.desc {
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>What we are here to do!</h2>
    <p>Example</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>What we have completed</h2>
    <p>Recent work (can include pictures)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>Company Description</h2>
    <p>EXAMPLE!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will work not so good because we can here different width of elements jsfiddle.net/uqr20k64/1 `space-between` just adds equal spaces between elements. This property doesn't care about equality of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
    body{
      width:900px;
      align-items:center;
      margin:0 auto;
      }
```

I think it's helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this and define styles for your `body` or wraps this blocks in container. No need for `float` here. Demo:

```css
body {
  /* become a flex-container */
  display: flex;
  /* vertically center flex-items */
  align-items: center;
  /* centering for text, optional here */
  text-align: center;
  
  /* occupy all height */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* equal width for children */
body > * {
  flex: 1;
}

.desc {
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc1 {
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc2 {
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc1">
  <h2>What we are here to do!</h2>
  <p>Example</p>
</div>
<div class="desc2">
  <h2>What we have completed</h2>
  <p>Recent work (can include pictures)</p>
</div>
<div class="desc">
  <h2>Company Description</h2>
  <p>EXAMPLE!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to use the float you can simply remove the floats and enclose all your divs in a main div which alligns all text to center:

```css
.desc {
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc1 {
  color: skyblue;
}

.desc2 {
  color: skyblue;
}
.div1{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" >
<div class="desc1">
  <h2>What we are here to do!</h2>
  <p>Example</p>
</div>
<div class="desc2">
  <h2>What we have completed</h2>
  <p>Recent work (can include pictures)</p>
</div>
<div class="desc">
  <h2>Company Description</h2>
  <p>EXAMPLE!</p>
</div>
</div>
```